# Integral of derivative of function with constant support is zero: intuitive descriptioin sought

Tags: integration, derivatives

I am looking for an intuitive argument why the integral of the derivative of a function with compact support is zero. More formally, let $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function with compact support and at least one derivative. For the integral of the derivative we easily find:
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{d\phi(t)}{dt} dt&=\lim_{a\to\infty}\phi(a)-\phi(-a)\\
&= 0
\end{align}
Now I try to understand this more intuitive.

- In some limited interval, $\phi$ is some non zero bump or jitter, lets say $\geq 0$ for simplicity.
- In this interval, the derivative is some differently formed non zero curve.
- The mean value theorem (intuitive enough, lets say) tells me that the derivative must change sign, so there are negative parts and positive parts.

The latter tells me that there is indeed the chance that the negative and positive parts cancel out over the integral.

What I am looking for is an eye-opener explaining why the negative and positive parts need to cancel out exactly. Something based on the two graphs of the function and its derivative would be nice.

Comment: The fundamental theorem of calculus is already super intuitive though. The total change is the sum of all the little changes. In this case the total change $\phi(a) - \phi(-a)$ is clearly $0$.

Answer (score 1):

One intuitive argument I found, though not along the function graphs: if I interpret $\phi(t)$ as a velocity, then its derivative is the acceleration. When starting from velocity $0$, then having some acceleration or deceleration phases and ending up with velocity $0$ again, obviously acceleration and deceleration must have cancelled out.

(This question+answer is really a border case with regard to https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26575/121890 .-)